# Jordan canonical form with 2 is the dimension of eigenespace,

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

> $$B= \begin{pmatrix}
>       0  & 1 & 0 \\
>       -4 & 4 & 0 \\ 
>       -2 & 1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$ I need to find Jordan decomposition of B.

My sketch:

We find Jordan's matrix first $A$ similar to matrix $B$, and matrix $C \in (3,\mathbb{C})$, such that $B = C^{-1}AC$ We have:
$$F_{B}(t)=\text{det}(\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
     -t  & 1 & 0 \\
     -4 & 4-t & 0 \\ 
     -2 & 1 & 2-t
\end{array}
\right))=(2-t)(-4t+t^{2}+4)=(2-t)^{3}$$
$$\text{SP}(B) = {2}$$
$\text{SP}$ means the spectrum of endomorphism.
We are now defining a subspace
$$\begin{bmatrix}
     -2  & 1 & 0 \\
     -4 & 2 & 0 \\ 
     -2 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
           x_{1} \\
           x_{2} \\
           x_{3}
\end{bmatrix}
\iff x_{1}= -\frac{1}{2}x_{2}
$$
So we have two eigenvectors:

$$V_{1}=\begin{bmatrix}
-2 \\
1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$ V_{2}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
 so, $2$ is the dimension of the eigenspace, therefore A is not diagonalizable and Jordan canonical form is

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
    -2 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -2  & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & -2 
\end{pmatrix}{}$

I have issue with last sequence. 
Why $B$ have this specify form $J$ with 1 for second row?

Comment: your eigenvalues are 2 not -2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not sure if I understood you question correctly but :

Firstly since the eigenvalue is 2 we have: 
 $A=\begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 2  & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 2 
\end{pmatrix}{}$
Also by changing the arrangement of the eigenvectors/extend-eigenvectors in the transformation matrix we could also get:
$A=\begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 1& 0 \\
    0 & 2  & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 2 
\end{pmatrix}{}$
hence the 1 being in the second row is not important or fixed.

In general you can change the order of the Jordan-Blocks by as you wish by changing the order of the vectors in the transformation matrix

Comment: I try understanding why I should added 1 to second row. Now it's mnemotechnic

Comment: Ah ok now i get your question

Comment: A proof for why the Jordan decomposition works is rather long. In my lecture notes we had 15 pages devoted to the subject (the proof wsa short but needed quite a lot of buildup). On the bright side it is such a standard subject that you are bound to find an online lecture notes explaining everything.

Comment: http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masdf/alg1/lec_notes_revised_at_the_end.pdf